# Automatically simulate SVN merges at each new commit

Tags: visual-studio, svn, merge, versioning

I'm working under Windows 7 / Visual Studio 2008 with TortoiseSVN as client.
My project has many branches, and i'm frequently getting merge conflicts/tree conflicts, especially due to files physically moved or deleted.

As I don't push revisions from branch to branch every day, sometimes it could be hard to solve these conflicts at the time of merge.

So I would like to introduce a "fail fast" approach, based on a simple idea : everytime a new commit happen in a specific branch, a tool automatically retrieves the commit, and try to merge it to some predefined other branch(es), just as the "Test" feature of Tortoise does. And warns me if one or more conflicts occurs.

Everything must run on client, i don't have access to the repositories server.

CommitMonitor allows user to get notified when a commit happen, but it doesn't help to anticipate further merge issues.

Thank you very much for your advices

Answer (score 1):

> everytime a new commit happen in a specific branch

It's post-commit hook

> new commit happen in a specific branch

I.e. you have already Working Copy of this branch

> try to merge it to some predefined other branch(es)

It's `svn merge` with `--dry-run option`

**Joining of the above notes:**

Your tool is post-commit hook in TortoiseSVN or repository (or independent bat-file), which, inside your WC, perform some set of

`svn merge --dry-run URL-OF-BRANCH`

commands (one merge per tested branch). Results of every merge (on STDOUT) you have to verify by hand

Comment: Thank you. As i stand in the question i don't have direct access to server (to put something like a post-commit hook). I was more thinking to a tool which "probes" periodically server for new commits. And I was hoping an automated tool, eventually with GUI, rather than scripting action directly with "svn" command lines. And, of course, i could perfectly have a local workspace for merge testing.

Comment: If it's not *your branch* (commit to which you monitor for test-merges), then you a) yes, have to have separate WC for foreign branch b) use "smart" commit monitor, which can perform predefined actions (your bat-file at least) in case of new commit - it can be [Vercue](http://www.vercue.com/) (maybe even Free Edition, which allow one rule)